# What constitutes a 'guest' account on Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard

I've seen the various reports that data can be lost on Snow Leopard when a user logs into a guest account and then back into their main account.  However, those terms are a bit nebulous to me.  What constitutes a guest account and a main account?

Background: on my machines (one Leopard, one Snow Leopard), there are a number of users.  One is the system administrator, who has sudo privileges.  I have my own main account which does not have sudo privileges.  There are also accounts for my kids.  Do any of those qualify as a 'guest' user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guest account is basically a built-in temporary account that can log in without a password. You can use it to let other people on your computer if you don't want them on one of the other accounts. The account cannot be accessed remotely and all files that are saved in it's home directory are deleted when the account is logged out. It is disabled by default:

[image]

Comment: OK - it is an 'official' term.  That helps a lot - and none of my accounts is a guest account within the meaning of that term.